# How to use a method in a string property using mvvm?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have a string property that is linked to a label in my XAML.

```
 public string CalorieenDoel
 {
      get { return $"Je mag nog {CalorieenOver2} calorieën eten!"; }
 }
```

CalorieenOver2 is my method

```
 public decimal CalorieenOver2()
    {
        decimal resultaat = 0;
        foreach (var item in LijstDagboeken)
        {
            resultaat += decimal.Parse(item.BerekenCalorieen);
        }
        resultaat = Doel - resultaat;
        return resultaat;
    }
```

How can I do this?
I solved it for now with a get property, is this the right way?

```
    public decimal CalorieenOver
    {
        get
        {
            decimal resultaat = 0;
            foreach (var item in LijstDagboeken)
            {
                resultaat += decimal.Parse(item.BerekenCalorieen);
            }
            resultaat = Doel - resultaat;
            return resultaat;
        }
    }

    public string CalorieenDoel
    {
        get { return $"Je mag nog {CalorieenOver} calorieën eten!"; }
    }
```

Comment: You could do it either way: `$"Je mag nog {CalorieenOver2()} calorieën eten!";`.

Comment: You also need to consider that if you are binding this property, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that your xaml made aware when this property has changed.

Comment: Ok I will do that, thank you for the quick response.